# Groovy match endswith regex

Tags: java, groovy

In Groovy 2.5, trying match string end with `'qa_prd'` or `'qa-prd'` value.

All of the below matches not working. What is the right way to test this in Groovy?

```
String imageTag ='project_qa-prd'

println imageTag.toLowerCase().endsWith(/qa[-_]prd?$/)
println imageTag.toLowerCase().endsWith(/qa[-_]prd$/)
println imageTag.toLowerCase().matches(/qa[-_]prd$/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
println imageTag.matches(/(?i).*qa[-_]prd$/)
```